# SQL Query, column SHOULD be present, but results states, it is not

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am having a hard time grasping why this query is telling me the TaxPayerID is NOT found, when in the beginning, I am clearly checking for it and only using the databases, which should contain the TaxPayerID column in the nTrucks table.

```
sp_MSforeachdb 
'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''nTrucks'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''TaxPayerID'')

BEGIN
    SELECT "?", nTrucks.UnitNumber, ntrucks.Companyid, nCompanyData.CompanyName, nTrucks.Owner, nTrucks.TaxPayerID
    FROM nTrucks
    INNER JOIN nCompanyData ON nTrucks.CompanyID = nCompanyData.CompanyID
    WHERE nTrucks.Owner like ''%Trucker%''
END
'
```

I am getting multiple 'Invalid column name 'TaxPayerID'.' errors, I assume it is from the databases NOT containing this column.

If anyone here can throw me a bone, a simple "you're a dummy, do it this way!", I would be very appreciative.

JF

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL inside dynamic SQL, I think.  You have a compile error, and this occurs before the `if` logic is run.

Comment: It runs if I take out the nTrucks.TaxPayerID on the line after the BEGIN. That's why I'm stumped.

Comment: Your second statement needs to select from `[?]..nTrucks`, not just `nTrucks`. `sp_MSforeachdb` doesn't automatically change the database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks! I wasn't sure how to do that exactly. But learned a lot tonight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a dummy! (you asked for it) :)

How to debug this error:

Locate the database that throws an error and try executing an actual SQL query on it directly to see if it will compile:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''nTrucks'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''TaxPayerID'')

BEGIN
    SELECT nTrucks.UnitNumber, ntrucks.Companyid, nCompanyData.CompanyName, nTrucks.Owner, nTrucks.TaxPayerID
    FROM nTrucks
    INNER JOIN nCompanyData ON nTrucks.CompanyID = nCompanyData.CompanyID
    WHERE nTrucks.Owner like ''%Trucker%''
END
```

It will fail.

Now you know that SQL server checks schema at query parse time rather than run time.
Then you follow @GordonLinoff suggestion and convert the `SELECT` query into dynamic SQL as follows:

```
sp_MSforeachdb 
'

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [?].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''nTrucks'' AND COLUMN_NAME = ''TaxPayerID'')

BEGIN
    EXEC( 
    ''SELECT "?", nTrucks.UnitNumber, ntrucks.Companyid, nCompanyData.CompanyName, nTrucks.Owner, nTrucks.TaxPayerID
    FROM [?]..nTrucks
    INNER JOIN [?]..nCompanyData ON nTrucks.CompanyID = nCompanyData.CompanyID
    WHERE nTrucks.Owner like ''''%Trucker%''''
    '' )
END

'
```

(I hope I got my quotes right)

If your query is supposed to reference a central nCompareData table then remove `[?]..` before nCompareData

Comment: `sp_MSforeachdb` doesn't automatically change the current database. I believe the problem is in `FROM nTrucks`. It should be `FROM [?]..nTrucks`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I am certainly a dummy

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid,  You are not wrong, I tested `EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
 'SELECT DB_NAME()'` - same value returned many times

Comment: Can you change your answer to reflect that? I'd rather have a correct answer, and I'd rather not write it up myself. In fact I'm pretty sure this has probably already been answered somewhere!

Comment: +1 fair enough :) I did indeed ask for it.

You guys are the best! the above actually worked ;)  THANK YOU! I was starting to think I was going nuts!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - I did update the answer straight away (not sure why you missed the update). It probably was answered somewhere before but what are the odds that the other answer starts with "You're a dummy!"?

Comment: Right!? This answer is definitely the GOLD answer! if I could you give gold, I would ;) Thanks for your help.